# Angular 2 - Pass data from one controller to another

Tags: angular

I would like to pass data from the `parent` controller to the `child` controller, when the user `click` on an element existing the `parent`.

Eg.

```
<div (click)="PassDataToChild(orderNo)"></div>
```

.ts

```
PassDataToChild(orderNo){
//Got the orderNo
//How to send it to the child component, and let the child read it?
}
```

Comment: The child should not know anything about the parent component. It sounds like you have a design issue here. All components should apply the Single Responsibility Principal.

Comment: what does the child component look like?  you don't usually need a function to pass to the child, just make sure the child is accepting a property that matches the `ng-model` of the parent....

Comment: @Claies @Jamie R well I just want to pass a piece of info from component A to B, I've done that on `Ionic 2` easily knowing that is based On Angular2; however, I can't figure out how to do it in Angular!

Comment: It shouldn't be any different??

Comment: @Claies which means?

Comment: Ionic 2 isn't *based* on angular, it **is** angular.  If you can do this in ionic2 why are you doing it any other way?

Comment: On Ionic 2, you have the option to pass data between controllers as simple as this : `this.nav.push({data:"data to pass"})` which is not valid on Angular

Comment: huh? isn't valid in angular?  what are you talking about?  first, `this.nav.push` implies that `nav` is an array that you are pushing a value into, which I'm not sure how that has anything to do with passing data to a component.  secondly, the only reason that `push` wouldn't be valid in angular (which is a framework, not a language) is that whatever you are trying to push into isn't an array (which makes sense, since you seem to be asking about how to pass to a component, which definitely isn't an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@Input()` decorator to pass data from Parent to Child.

**Code is attached below**

```
import {Component, Input} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'child-comp',
    template: '<div>{{orderNo}}</div>'
})

export class Child {
    @Input() orderNo: string;
}



import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'parent-comp',
    template: '<div (click)="PassDataToChild()"></div> <child-comp [orderNo]="orderNo"></child-comp>'
})

export class Parent {
    orderNo: string;

    PassDataToChild() {
        this.orderNo = 'Dummy Order';
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this got downvoted, it looks like a valid answer to me...

Comment: Yeah even I do agree with you. Its a common and valid question.